# Connect generator to main panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel, generator

I want to connect a generator with a 50 amp power inlet box but as you can see from the picture, there's no space to install the circuit. Am i missing something? This main panel connects to a subpanel in the garage.

[image]

Comment: Who do you have for an electrical utility?  Also, why are you seeking to do whole-house transfer? (Posting a photo of your subpanel's directory can help us help you figure out which loads actually need to be run off the generator and which loads can stay on normal power)

Answer (score 3):

One manual transfer mechanism is the circuit breaker interlock. Since you mentioned "there's no space to install the circuit" I infer this is the kind you're thinking of. You're right: the meter base and disconnect pictured here cannot support generator inlet and interlock. There are several models on the US market that do support this. They're often called "meter main" or "all-in-one" or CSED (combination service entrance device). So one way to accomplish your generator inlet objective is to replace your existing panel with one of these. This can also give you spaces for grid-tie solar, vehicle charging, an additional subpanel in the house, and so on.

Another viable manual transfer mechanism is to add some kind of switching box "beside" this existing panel (literally beside it outdoors is common, but it could go indoors or elsewhere if you preferred). This could actually be done *simply by adding another circuit breaker panel* and set it up with a main breaker, interlock, and generator breaker. The only difference to the approach above is that the utility meter can remain as-is, where-is, and perhaps you save a small amount of time and cost.

There also are "manual transfer switch" products which are just a box with a giant switch inside. Operation of these is perhaps easier to explain or understand. With the interlock one must do a three-step procedure (flip the main breaker, slide the interlock, flip the generator breaker), but with a manual transfer switch, it's simply pull the switch this way for utility; push it that way for generator.

I think people usually pick the new panel with interlock approach because it's more commonly available, likely less expensive, and carries the benefit of adding extra breaker spaces.

Automatic transfer schemes are also possible. These take care of switching the building over to generator power automatically, then switching the building back after utility power is restored. An automatic transfer switch is usually a separate box on the wall, though at least one breaker panel manufacturer offers a breaker panel that can hold a manual or automatic transfer switch (Siemens "generator ready" load center).

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, you're missing a transfer switch. I doubt you'll find one that fits inside the panel. If you were going to hook up to a generator that would feed your entire house, you could install a transfer switch next to your main panel and the outlet for the generator next to it. If you're only planning on serving only partial load of your house, your transfer switch would be mounted close to your subpanel with the outlet going back outside.

Comment: Also referred to as an _interlock_? Or is that something different?

Comment: @isherwood It's two different ways to achieve the same thing.  An interlock is a sliding plate covering the breakers, that lets you turn on the grid supply, or the generator supply, but not both at the same time.  A transfer switch is a big rotary switch.

Comment: @isherwood  An interlock is a latching device that would prevent your generator breaker  and main breaker from both being on at the same time. In order for it to work,  your main breaker and generator breaker have to be in the same panel.  It wouldn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This thing is not a panel.  It is only a meter with a built-in disconnect, otherwise known as a "meter-main".  If it is labeled "not service equipment" then it isn't even your main breaker.

Your generator interlock will go in your interior panel and act between the main breaker and tge generator breaker.  If it's a convertible panel (made to have a main breaker retrofitted), do that.

If there is no option to retrofit a main breaker, then you'd need an inline transfer switch.  A great choice for this is a "trailer panel" or "ranch panel" which has 8 breaker spaces and thru lugs.  2 of the breaker spaces take the generator interlock, then you have 6 more spares.